# generate css file with php file

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm building a wordpress theme options page using the redux framework. I read al the data in my style.php file and i will include that file in de header so the custom css is loaded.

style.php:

```
<?php
?>
body {
    background-color:<?php global $variable; echo $variable['color-background'];?>;
    font-family:<?php global $variable; echo $variable['typography6']['font-family'];?>;
}

a {
    color: <?php global $variable; echo $variable['link-color']['regular'];?>;
}

<?php
?>
```

header.php:

```
<style>
<?php require_once('css/style.php');?>
</style>
```

Now its all messy in the head of my website. It would be great if it automatically generates a css file. Does anyone know a good option?

Comment: [How can I use WordPress functions in my stylesheet?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/54583)

Answer (score 1):

You can define your PHP file as a CSS file by writing `header("Content-type: text/css");` at the start.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css");
?>
body {
    background-color:<?php global $variable; echo $variable['color-background'];?>;
    font-family:<?php global $variable; echo $variable['typography6']['font-family'];?>;
}
...
```

If you do so you can link it with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.php">` in `header.php`

Comment: the problem with that is that returns an css file without the variables:body {
 background-color:;
 font-family:;
}

a {
 color: ;
}

Comment: Where are these variables defined?

Comment: This answers the original question, and worked great for me. Thanks! @luukgruijs: you might be missing a PHP include?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?PHP
echo '<style>';
?>

body {
background-color:<?php global $variable; echo $variable['color-background'];?>;
font-family:<?php global $variable; echo $variable['typography6']['font-family'];?>;
}

<?PHP
echo '</style>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Redux Framework already has a built-in feature to update css file dynamically using compiler argument in field array configuration http://docs.reduxframework.com/redux-framework/advanced/integrating-a-compiler/

Or you can use output argument to output you custom css directly in head tag http://docs.reduxframework.com/redux-framework/the-basics/output-2/

I'm using the first option and enqueue the css file generated through wp_enqueue_style native wp function.